# Callback from Delphi DLL to C# - only works in idle winform or using app.doevents?

Tags: c#, delphi, service, callback

I give up, I have to write and ask; I'm using an unmanaged DLL written in Delphi, which asynchronously invokes a (parameterless) callback passed to it whenever an event occurs in the hardware it is developed to monitor.

What I do in C# is I keep a static reference to a created delegate, which is then passed as parameter to the start method on the Delphi side. This tells the DLL to notify me using the callback, whenever there is new data to fetch, using a GetData method.

All works fine, real fine, until I try to do the exact same thing in a console app, or in a windows service. Or if I create and call the DLL related methods on a separate thread without letting that thread spin doing Application.DoEvents(). Usually people with similar problems seem to have had problems with the GC or calling conventions, but having (attempted to) secured against GC issues by keeping the delegate ref I stand without further clues on how to solve this.

I'm assuming I'm missing something paramount in how the CLR invokes my callbacks after the DLL calls the thunk provided to connect to my callback handler.

The declarations of my DLL imports look like this:

```
    [DllImport("TheDelphiApi.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern UInt32 Start(MulticastDelegate callback);

    [DllImport("TheDelphiApi.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern void GetData(byte[] recdata);

    public delegate void EngineCallbackHandler();                     

    private static EngineCallbackHandler engineCallback;
```

And the call setting up the callback:

```
        UInt32 result = Start(engineCallback);
```

Got clues? What's with the need for DoEvents? Any feedback is really appreciated, been trying research this for a few days now, without any indications on progress.
/J

Comment: No clues with the given code. You're saying it needs a winform to run. Maybe the code needs a winform message queue to operate on the Delphi side?

Comment: Not according to the Delphi developer, he uses it in services (and what not) without problems.

Comment: A Delphi service has an active message pump.

Comment: @Marjan Interesting! Would that message pump be critical to the DLLs ability to respond to callbacks being made to it from another DLL it in turn references?

Comment: I would say so. The message pump in a Delphi service would be a mechanism by which code in DLL can get executed. See answer by Thorsten for the two ways in which DLL code can get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the native code, but I would assume that the code on the native side depends on a message loop being processed on the thread that calls Start? e.g. because it's using a TTimer or similar?

Once the call to Start has returned, there is only 2 ways how any code can get executed inside that DLL. Either a new thread was started, or a timer or some other mechanism has been registered which depends on window messages.

EDIT:

Another possibility:

If the native DLL is using cross-process COM in an STA (single threaded apartment) then COM depends on a working message loop.

Comment: I will investigate if there is such a component in use somewhere in the Delphi DLL. Sure sounds like a plausible explanation. Putting an Application.DoEvents on an internal thread loop in the service solves the problem. I get the general impression it isn't a very nice way to solve this, but I guess it works in the meantime.

Comment: Well, if a certain library requires a working message loop, then it requires a working message loop. That's not an uncommon requirement (e.g. same applies if you are using COM with an STA). But it is a requirement that should be clearly documented.

Comment: I see. There is no COM involved. My callback is invoked from the DLL as a response to an interrupt-driven callback from an UDP communications library. So as far as I understand it, there should be no dependency on message pumping. But I have to admit my understanding of how it all "clings" is very limited.

Comment: Basic question: do you expect that engineCallback to be called on the same thread that called Start? If yes, then message pumping is the only way how that (or any for that matter) native library can "break into" that thread to call your callback. Also, there is no COM involved between your managed code and the native code, but that doesn't guarantee that the native code isn't using COM internally. If you are willing to accept that callbacks can happen in the context of a different thread, the native code could start a thread of it's own and make callbacks in that context.

Comment: I see! Now that explains it. For all I care it could be any thread, another would be preferrable to having to reference sys.win.forms and spinning on an app.doevents just to make things work. Thanks a million for magical words. Things seem clear now.