# Console Application with Message Pump

Tags: c#, .net, loops, message

I'm trying to write a console application (C# .NET) that makes use of un-managed code in a 3rd party DLL.

The external assembly makes extensive use of callbacks.  The sample application I have uses Windows Forms.

The sample code (Windows Forms) makes use of ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ConnectToControlPanel));
```

It would seem that with windows forms there is a message pump that handles the callbacks.  This is not the case with a console app so I need to construct my own.

I've tried adding a reset event

```
private static ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

static void main()
{
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ConnectToControlPanel));
      resetEvent.WaitOne();
}

private void ConnectToControlPanel()
{
   //Call external function from unmanaged DLL
   resetEvent.Set();
}
```

That doesn't work.

My problem seems to be very much [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661308/callback-from-delphi-dll-to-c-sharp-only-works-in-idle-winform-or-using-app-do/5662764#5662764) but there is no real solution other than using Win.Forms and calling Application.DoEvents()

**Edit**

I modified my code thus:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConnectToControlPanel());
            while (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
```

This works, the callbacks get called on progress and the result is successful rather than a timeout.

It doesn't feel right though to have to run that ugly loop every time I make an external call.

I've also tried spinning up another thread that constantly calls `Application.DoEvents()` but that didn't work, so I'm assuming it's got something to do with running in the same thread that made the call.

Comment: Could you please add more details about what doesn't work ? If there is any error, please include them as well. I don't think Message Pump (an UI concept) and QueueUserWorkItem (a threading concept) are directly related.

Comment: In the Wndows.Forms version, the `ConnectToControlPanel` method calls the external DLL's `ConnectPanel` method.  The Forms app then receives regular callbacks on progress until a connection (in this case TCP) is made and the `ConnectPanel` call returns a result.  In my console application the call eventually times out and none of the callback methods  are ever received.

Comment: Sounds like your unmanaged code needs a message loop to be handled. Have you tried running this code in Windows Forms application that doesn't have a form? You can always allocate console manually if you need it.

Comment: Sergey that looks to be the case, and yes, if I run a traditional Win Forms app things do work.  I do get an ugly blank form displayed at runtime however, and ultimately this console app needs to run on Mono where there is no GUI to speak of.

Comment: @GavinHill, Just seen your update to the original question. Have you tried calling `Application.Run()` without creating a form, instead of `Application.DoEvents()` ?

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin I have, but firstly is creates a small, blank form at runtime, I'm not sure how to prevent that.  Secondly, Main blocks at Application.Run, so would I need to kick off all of my activity (connection, polling, error handling, user interaction, etc) from the form constructor?

Comment: @GavinHill, there is a parameterless overload of `Application.Run()` that doesn't seem to create any windows (at least Spy++ doesn't show anything) - you should try calling it from your console application. And yes, it blocks the thread, so you will have to interact with console in another thread. Calling `Application.Exit()` should force it to return.

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin So I tried:to start a new thread to interact with the console (var t = new Thread(DoStuffMethod).Start()) and then called Application.Run and I get the same timeout and no callbacks, so that's not a feasible solution I'm afraid.